# My Perl module from CPAN won't install, what do I do?

Tags: perl, perl-module, cpan

This is a canonical question for the above problem, inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27891153/58074) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30627467/why-does-installing-numberformat-on-win-64-fail).  Please edit and improve it.

I'm trying to install a module from CPAN, using the CPAN/cpanm/CPANPLUS client.  However, I'm getting build or test errors when I try to install it.  What should I do?

Comment: Once this gets into shape, perhaps we should link it to the cpan or perl tag-wikis

Comment: I've never got cpan to work first time on tens of new fresh linux installs. I wonder if any ever tests it?

Answer (score 3):

### Does it build at all?

The first thing to consider is, is your module building at all?  If it isn't building, you should check for existing bug reports, file one if necessary, and perhaps try to fix the issue yourself (steps 2 and 3b/3c below).

If it builds but tests fail, follow these steps.

### 1. Determine if the test is valid

The purpose of these tests is to *test*. If there's a problem, you need to know about it, and not sweep it under the rug. Resolve the issue one way or another. Is there a problem with something on your system, or is this a problem with the test itself. If this is a problem with the test, does it still affect you? If this is a system problem, is this something you might run into? For example, let's say there's a test that checks for connectivity between your system and a Windows system. If you don't connect to Windows systems, maybe that particular test doesn't apply to you.

## 2. Check MetaCPAN for bug reports

If you have a test failure, go to the [MetaCPAN](http://metacpan.org) webpage for that module, and check the left hand side for RT [issues](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=Date-Calc) to see if someone else is getting the same errors.  If no one is, you should open an RT ticket, or a ticket in the project's bug tracker of choice.

There may be patches available from other users.  If the patches make sense to you, you can try applying them and rerunning the tests.

You can also click on the *Testers* link on MetaCPAN. The QA testers webpage will show you the various Perl versions, module versions, platforms, and show you which tests are failing on particular platforms on which versions. You might need to install an alternative version of the module.

At this point, there are a few paths you can take.

## 3a. Force the installation

Only once you've determined that the failed test doesn't necessarily apply to you, do a *force* install:

```
cpan> force install Date::Calc
```

This will run through the entire install, except that it will skip all testing. (Or maybe it still tests, but doesn't fail if a test fails.). The module will still fail on compiler errors, or if something can't get written to your system. It merely ignores tests.

This should be the last desperate attempt to get something installed. You've should have already resolved that the failed tests are bugs or not meaningful for you. Or, someone is standing beside you with a gun to your head saying, *"Install that module, or I'll pull the trigger!"*.

## 3b. Find an alternative module

Or, you can decide to use another module.  CPAN is full of various approaches to problems ([TMTOWTDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it)), so there many be one there that does what you want.

## 3c. Write some code

Or, you can analyze why the test is failing and either fix the module or the code.  Bug reports with potential patches are often appreciated by busy module authors.  If it doesn't look like the author wants to take your fix, you can always fork an existing module, or write a fresh one.

If the author has gone MIA, you may be able to [adopt the module](http://neilb.org/adoption/) and maintain it yourself.  The [general process for adopting a module](http://neilb.org/2013/07/24/adopt-a-module.html) is first to try to submit code to the author that fixes it, and then wait a while, maybe a month, for the author to pick it up.  If there's no response, try alternative means of contact, email, Google+, whatever you can find.  After that, you can go on Perl IRC chats, mailing lists, etc, looking for someone who knows where the author might be.  If none of that works after a few months, the PAUSE admins can investigate and turn the module over to you.

[This is based on this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27891153/58074)